# Convert an Expression Tree to Source Code string

Tags: .net, lambda

I have a function that has the following signature...

```
public string DoJunk(Expression<Func<bool>> expression)
```

I'm trying to find a way to convert the "expression" parameter back to something resembling the original source code (or at least a c# representation of the original souce code). So, if someone calls the function like this...

```
DoJunk(() => (i + j) * 9 == Math.Round((double)j / (i - 3), 4))
```

...I'd like to be able to convert the expression to this...

```
(i + j) * 9 == Math.Round((double)j / (i - 3), 4)
```

Has anyone done this?

Comment: I'm experimenting with some ideas for a unit testing framework. My idea is that if you test against a lambda and the test fails, you could actually show the code that failed. For example, instead of getting "expected: 4 actual: 5", you could get a message more like "expected: user.Age == 4 actual: user.Age == 5"

Comment: You ask for a C#-like string representation, but I've written [a library that outputs other representations](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreeToString): Visual Basic - like, factory methods needed to create a similar expression; object/collection initialization syntax.

Answer (score 14):

I've just happened across this; I've written a free, open-source library which provides an extension method to create a source-code-like string from an Expression:

```
using AgileObjects.ReadableExpressions;

var myExpression = CreateBigExpressionTree();
var expressionSource = myExpression.ToReadableString();
```

I've written [a blog](https://agileobjects.co.uk/readable-expression-trees-debug-visualizer) about it, the source is [on GitHub](https://github.com/AgileObjects/ReadableExpressions), there's [a NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AgileObjects.ReadableExpressions) containing the extension method, and I've written a set of Debugger Visualizers for VS 2010 -> 2022 which are in [the Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1232914.ReadableExpressionsVisualizers).

Comment: Well, looking at the nuget download count, this is way more in demand than I expected.

Comment: I have [a mapper project](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AgileObjects.AgileMapper) which depends on it - that will have increased the download count. AutoMapper have recommended my library for examining their mapping execution plans, too! :)

Comment: That explains it :)

Answer (score 9):

Here's an interesting article, with code, discussing the conversion of expression trees back into something that resembles (roughly) the original source:

> [Expression Trees-Lambdas to CodeDom Conversion](https://linq2codedom.codeplex.com/)

As a side-note, have you tried calling the expression's `ToString` method?

```
Expression<Func<int, int, bool>> expr =
    (i, j) => (i + j) * 9 == Math.Round((double)j / (i - 3), 4);

Console.WriteLine(expr.ToString());
// (i, j) => (Convert(((i + j) * 9)) = Round((Convert(j) / Convert((i - 3))), 4))

Console.WriteLine(expr.Body.ToString());
// (Convert(((i + j) * 9)) = Round((Convert(j) / Convert((i - 3))), 4))
```

Comment: I have tried using ToString(), but it gives me something pretty nasty looking...
(Convert(((value(LambdaToStringSpike.Program+<>c__DisplayClass0).i + value(LambdaToStringSpike.Program+<>c__DisplayClass0).j) * 9)) = Round((Convert(value(LambdaToStringSpike.Program+<>c__DisplayClass0).j) / Convert((value(LambdaToStringSpike.Program+<>c__DisplayClass0).i - 3))), 4))

Comment: Yep, I think the output you're seeing is what's generated behind-the-scenes by the C# compiler to handle the captured variables `i` and `j`. In my examples, `i` and `j` are locals, so the output is much closer to the original source code.