# Converting Expression<T, bool> to String

Tags: c#, expression, dynamic-linq

I need a way to recreate dynamically generated reports at some point in the future. Long story short, I need to store a specific linq query (different for each report) into database and then execute the query with dynamic Linq later on.

This is all good, but I can't find a way to convert expression to string.

As in:

```
Expression<Product, bool> exp = (x) => (x.Id > 5 && x.Warranty != false);
```

should become:

```
"Product.Id > 5 && Product.Warranty != false"
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I think you are asking `Expression<Func<Product,bool>>`, I have modified your question.

Comment: This is roughly the same question as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217961/serializing-and-deserializing-expression-trees-in-c

Comment: Yes, that's correct, I left the func part out.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/exprserialization

Comment: What is wrong with `ToString()` ?

Comment: @leppie: ToString() apparently returns metadata from reflection, not the actual string representation of the lambda expression.

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert-an-expression-tree-to-source-code-string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402839/convert-an-expression-tree-to-source-code-string)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This may not be the best/most efficient method, but it *does* work.

```
Expression<Func<Product, bool>> exp = (x) => (x.Id > 5 && x.Warranty != false);

string expBody = ((LambdaExpression)exp).Body.ToString(); 
// Gives: ((x.Id > 5) AndAlso (x.Warranty != False))

var paramName = exp.Parameters[0].Name;
var paramTypeName = exp.Parameters[0].Type.Name;

// You could easily add "OrElse" and others...
expBody = expBody.Replace(paramName + ".", paramTypeName + ".")
                 .Replace("AndAlso", "&&");


Console.WriteLine(expBody);
// Output: ((Product.Id > 5) && (Product.Warranty != False))
```