# .NET - dump statement lambda body to string

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

Given the following statement lambda example:

```
var fMyAction = new Action(() =>
 {
    x += 2;
    something = what + ever; 
 });
```

What are possible ways to get the body of that lambda and dump it to string? (Something that will ultimately allow to write an extension method for `Action` class of this kind: `fMyAction.Dump()` which will return `"x += 2; something = what + ever;"`).

Thanks

Comment: What is it for? Please give more background on your question, probably there is a completely different solution. What you're trying to do now is almost impossible and does not make any sense in C-sharp.

Comment: @SK-logic: That would be definitely out of the scope of this specific post to discuss my own reasons on abstract level.

Comment: you won't get a useful answer without explaining at least why do you need a string representation, how close this string should be to an original source, and what are your performance requirements. There are several options available besides decompilation.

Comment: @SK-logic: thank you for your interest, but I think I've got quite a useful answer to my quite a straightforward question

Comment: [mono.linq.expressions](http://evain.net/blog/articles/2010/06/23/mono-linq-expressions/) does this, but then its only meant for expression trees. Another related question: [serializing-and-deserializing-expression-trees-in-c-sharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217961/serializing-and-deserializing-expression-trees-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not possible in that form. Your lamda gets compiled to byte-code. While in theory it's possible to decompile the byte-code, just like reflector does, it's difficult, error prone and doesn't give you the exact code you compiled, but just code that's equivalent.

If you [use an `Expression<Action>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4793981/11683) instead of just `Action` you get the expression tree describing the lamda. And converting an expression tree to a string is possible(and there are existing libraries which do it).

But that's not possible in your example because it's a multi statement lamda. And only simple lamdas can be automatically converted to an expression tree.

Comment: You are right... I found this and was ready to open champagne: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/exprserialization Then all of a sudden: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397745.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Read through the tutorial here,

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2007/07/30/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-i.aspx

Pay close attention to the visitor pattern he uses to walk a given expression tree. You should be able to alter it to fit your needs easy enough.