# get a string with the content of Action parameter in c#

Tags: c#

I have this code

```
static void TaskRun(Action action)
{
    Task.Run(() => { try { action();} catch {}});
}

static void Run()
{
    TaskRun(() => {int a =5; a = a *5;})
}
```

I want to get the content of the action parameters as string (e.g. `"int a =5; a = a *5;"`) in my TaskRun function.

The reason is that i want to wrap all the Task.run with the try catch and in my catch i want to print the code that causes the crash

Comment: Are you asking for a way to convert any delegate body into string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET - dump statement lambda body to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922307/net-dump-statement-lambda-body-to-string)