# Get property name from a lambda which takes a dynamic parameter as input

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, lambda

I'm designing a test API. I want to have an API like:

```
// There is a dynamic object which should be tested to have certain properties.
dynamic result = SomeMethod();

AssertPropertyIsNotNull(resut, o => o.Title);
AssertPropertyIsNotNull(resut, o => o.City.Name);
```

I want to write `TestProperty` method to assert the property and shows a **proper message** it it fails like:

```
private void AssertPropertyIsNotNull(dynamic result, Func<dynamic, object> propertySelector)
{
    var propertyPath = GetPropertyPathFromFunc(propertySelector);
    var errorMessage = $"{propertyPath} is not filled properly."
    Assert.IsNotNull(propertySelector(result), errorMessage);
}
```

Here in this example, I need the body for `GetPropertyPathFromFunc`.

**Question** How can I write a method that gets a lambda like `o => City.Name` as input and returns a string like `"City.Name"` as result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215449/c-sharp-converting-lambda-expression-function-to-descriptive-string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using `dynamic` you loose type safety and compile time member name checking checking so it does not make any difference to use strings as property names.

Here is a solution. It needs extensive error checking and exception handling. You can also add caching mechanism to reduce reflection overhead.

```
public static bool IsPropertyNull(dynamic obj, string propertyName)
{
    var path = propertyName.Split('.');
    object tempObject = obj;
    for (int i = 0; i < path.Length; i++)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] dynamicProperties = tempObject.GetType().GetProperties();
        var property = dynamicProperties.Single(x => x.Name == path[i]);
        tempObject = property.GetValue(tempObject);
    }
    return tempObject == null;
}

bool isTitleNull = IsPropertyNull(result, "Title");
bool isCityNameNull = IsPropertyNull(result, "City.Name");
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted, unfortunately `dynamic` can't be used in expression trees as currently implemented by the C# compiler. As an alternative, you could invoke the delegate with a custom dynamic object which collects the property names accessed. I have demonstrated this below. Note that this only works with the limited syntax you have given, and I have not made a lot of effort to handle anything more complex.

```
private static string GetPropertyPathFromFunc(Func<dynamic, object> propertySelector)
{
    var collector = new PropertyNameCollector();
    propertySelector(collector);
    return collector.Name;
}

private class PropertyNameCollector : DynamicObject
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
            Name += ".";
        Name += binder.Name;
        result = this;
        return true;
    }
}
```