# Library for printing expressions

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I'm looking for the library which provides the expression printing functionality (from the lambdas converted to expression trees). In other words it should do similar job to parsing examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx), but should be obviously far more complete. Is anyone aware of such library?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? How should the printed expressions look like? Isn't `ToString()` good enough for you?

Comment: @svick: I'm not sure you've understood my question. Look at the examples in the link provided.

Comment: Why do you think I didn't understand your question? I looked at the example in the link, and it doesn't clarify what exactly you want. Could you answer my questions?

Comment: @svick: I thought that because of the `ToString()` suggestion. I've started to edit the question and then I understood *which* `ToString()` you were talking about. Didn't know that the to string on the expression object just pretty prints the expression! ;) Post it as an answer to have it accepted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert-an-expression-tree-to-source-code-string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402839/convert-an-expression-tree-to-source-code-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want some textual representation of the expression and you don't care how exactly does it look like, you can use `ToString()`. All of the [`Expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions) types override this method.

For example, for the simple expression `num => num < 5`, `ToString()` returns `num => (num < 5)`. But for more complicated expressions, it doesn't look like C# code anymore. For example, for `num => num < Math.Pow(5,5)`, it returns `num => (Convert(num) < Pow(5, 5))`.

Comment: It's just what I need. Sometimes the darkest place is under the candlestick ;)

Comment: Alternatively, for more complex cases: http://evain.net/blog/articles/2010/06/23/mono-linq-expressions

Comment: @konrad.kruczynski `ToString` is going to be slower (if you want to run it in a loop) compared to manually visiting each node and printing what you want.

Comment: @nawfal: it won't be a problem in my case.