# expression tree to source code conversion

Tags: c#, expression-trees

Is there a library which converts arbitrary c# expression trees to string (representing C# source which would build up that expression tree)

```
var expTree = ...;
var stringRepresentation = Library.ToCSharpSource(expTree); // <- something like this
Console.WriteLine("Debug info: " + stringRepresentation);
```

I've found this article: [Convert an Expression Tree to Source Code string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402839/convert-an-expression-tree-to-source-code-string) however, the link is not working anymore.

Comment: The link works for me...

Comment: http://www.canerten.com/meta-programming-with-expression-trees-lambdas-to-codedom-conversion/