# Roslyn: Expressions and SytnaxTree

Tags: expression-trees, roslyn

I am learning Roslyn and I wonder, is there any API to "convert" expression trees to Roslyn syntax trees ?

Answer (score 2):

there's no such API by now.

if you're seeking for a quick workaround, you could try to [convert the expression tree to source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402839/convert-an-expression-tree-to-source-code-string) firstly